# Why this add/removeClass isn't working?

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

This:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.klass').removeClass('klass');
});
$('.buddon').click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('klass');
    $('body').removeClass('klass2');
});
```

To my eyes this looks simple and should work but it is not :(

Comment: Share your html code.

Comment: Which of your add/removeClass aren't working?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: You said it looks simple, but to us, it looked like a mess. Please tell us what you are trying to accomplish here. Seems you wanted to remove the class 'klass' anywhere in the document, but that will fail, because there is no match.

Comment: The first part works fine. .Klass is removed on page load like it should. But when clicking on .buddon it is not coming back.

Comment: What's not coming back, the class 'klass' ? Well, it will never work unless you triggered it manually with an html element like a button, anchor or whatever, or programatically by calling .trigger('click')...

Comment: So clicking .buddon div is not enough to bring .klass div back?

Comment: Are you reading my comments? I already told you the answer earlier. It can be triggered 'manually' by clicking on any html element, such as a button, an anchor or whatever (can be a div, span, etcetera) as long as you have the class .buddon in it.

Comment: That's what I thought too. But nothing happens when clicking the the element.

Comment: It's working fine, see it here, use  'inspect element' when investigating and verifying the DOM changes. -- http://jsfiddle.net/cam3rmp5/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to include all the code in the `$(document).ready()`.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.klass').removeClass('klass');

    $('.buddon').click(function() {
        $('body').addClass('klass');
        $('body').removeClass('klass2');
    });
});
```

Comment: The click handler will still work even if it's outside of the doc ready handler, so that's not the problem. The problem is, the one asking the question doesn't specify the real problem.

Comment: Yes, his question is not clear. But click handler cannot work outside of the doc ready function if you are using jquery. Take a look http://plnkr.co/edit/Nmc80khArRr5tkaG71fd?p=preview

Comment: OK, probably you are right if you place javascript file on the bottom instead of on the top.

Comment: It works perfectly even if it's outside of the doc ready as long as jquery itself is loaded before the problematic scripts. see it here.... -- http://jsfiddle.net/cam3rmp5/1/

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('body').removeClass('klass');

 $('.buddon').click(function() {
     $('body').addClass('klass');
     $('body').removeClass('klass');
});

});
```

Comment: How can you supply an answer when you can't identify the problem?